# What is a simple way to analyze the performance of a simple Sprint Boot REST Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, query-optimization

What are some simple techniques/tools I can use to analyze code efficiency - and query efficiency for a simple REST service I have built in Spring Boot?

It does simple CRUD operations with some business logic on top of it.

It is taking 1 second to return so I would like to use this as an opportunity to learn how to analyze the code and queries on the database.

I'd prefer not to buy additional tooling. I use IntelliJ as my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your best starting place is the built in InteliJ profiling tools: https://lp.jetbrains.com/intellij-idea-profiler/

The idea is that you run your application and attach a 'profiler' to it - after running for a while the profiler will gather information about cpu/memory usage and display this information in a number of forms, a common one is a flame-graph (https://www.datadoghq.com/knowledge-center/distributed-tracing/flame-graph/)

Another good option is Glowroot https://glowroot.org/ which allows you to also analyse SQL queries and other metrics.